# Compile time array from C++ template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, variadic-templates

How can I at compile time create for example an std::array from a template parameter pack?

This shows what I need, but without a parameter pack.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct ToInfoArray
{
    static constexpr std::array<Info, 3> value = { { T1::info, T2::info, T3::info } };
};
```

[Live demo demonstrating the intended usage](http://cpp.sh/4rh5q)

**Bonus question:**
Would you use `std::array`, `array[]` or `std::initializer_list` as type for InfoArray?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct ToInfoArray
{
    static constexpr std::array<Info, sizeof...(Ts)> value = { { Ts::info... } };
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4071f61caa25638)

> *Would you use std::array, array[] or std::initializer_list as type for InfoArray?*

`std::array<T,N>`. It's an aggregate that behaves (with comparable performance) just like a regular array, but provides an additional interface for operating on its elements; itself, it's a copyable type.

`std::initializer_list` is not an option here for numerous reasons. Once it's used as a data member (with an in-class initializer), the elements it stores are invalidated after any of constructors' execution. It's not guaranteed to be a literal type, thus it can't be marked as `constexpr`. Its size is not usable (accessible) in constant expressions. It doesn't provide random access logic (without resorting to pointer arithmetic); the only way to enumerate its elements is to iterate from `begin()` to `end()`, which in addition yields pointers to constant items. `std::initializer_list` was designed to serve primarily as a function parameter.

Comment: Might want to note why you want `std::array`?

Answer (score 3):

With C++14, you can simply make it a variable template:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr std::array<Info, sizeof...(Ts)> value{{Ts::info...}};
```

Otherwise, the correct syntax for your usage is:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct ToInfoArray
{
    static constexpr std::array<Info, sizeof...(Ts)> value{{Ts::info...}};
};
```

And strongly prefer `std::array<>` to raw arrays or an `initializer_list`.